ubuntu 24.04 getting slow
after upgrading 24.04 LTS im facing system is performing very very slow even im using 250Gb  ssd, 8GB ddr4 ram, intel i5 9400f processor. and booting time is awesome it's taking around  1:30 sec. i can't find any sollution except downgrading.

You feel 90 secs to boot is slow?

before upgrade its tooks around 20 sec

You may want to edit the question and add that info.

Please add the output of the commands systemd-analyze blame and systemd-analyze critical-chain
